# SSLError when accessing SIDRA (IBGE) API using Python - [SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I've been using a Python script to access the SIDRA (IBGE) API and fetch data. It was working perfectly fine, but recently, without any changes on my part, I started encountering an SSL error. Here's the code I've been using:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v3/agregados'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.json())
```

Upon running the code, I get the following error:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='servicodados.ibge.gov.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/agregados (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1007)')))

Here are the things I've tried:

1. Using the verify=False option with requests.get().
2. Updating the requests and urllib3 libraries.
3. Trying other libraries like httpx and aiohttp.
4. Checking the OpenSSL version.

Nothing seems to solve the issue. I'm at a loss since the code used to work without any issues. Has anyone encountered this and knows a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import ssl

import requests


class TLSAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.set_ciphers("DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1")
        ctx.options |= 0x4   # <-- the key part here, OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT
        kwargs["ssl_context"] = ctx
        return super(TLSAdapter, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)


url = "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v3/agregados"

with requests.session() as s:
    s.mount("https://", TLSAdapter())
    print(s.get(url).json())
```

Prints:

```py
[{'id': 'D5', 'nome': 'Áreas Urbanizadas', 'agregados': [{'id': '8418', 'nome': 'Áreas urbanizadas,

...
```